# Count the number of links and divide them in 3 groups

Tags: javascript

I am developing a webpage for myself where I am fetching links to tutorials using a API. The problem is, there are lots of links to click on.

Is there any way in JavaScript to divide the links in 3 groups and have 3 buttons where on click they open all the links in group? Like, "Open First 1/3", "Open Second 1/3" and "Open Last 1/3"?

I tried to divide the links.length with 3, but it gives me a the result in decimal, like when the links count is 31, I am getting `10.3333333333`.

I am really clueless here. Any help will be appreciated. I know this question sounds kind of Do It For Me type, but believe me, its not. Just guiding me to the proper direction would be enough.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered what the result should be when the number of links is not divisible by 3?

Comment: @Unmitigated, yes. May be round the result (after division) to the next number.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would help.

```
 const linksCount = links.length;
const linksPerGroup = Math.ceil(linksCount / 3);

const firstGroupLinks = links.slice(0, linksPerGroup);
const secondGroupLinks = links.slice(linksPerGroup, linksPerGroup * 2);
const lastGroupLinks = links.slice(linksPerGroup * 2);

corresponding links

document.querySelector('#openFirstGroupButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  firstGroupLinks.forEach(link => window.open(link));
});

document.querySelector('#openSecondGroupButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  secondGroupLinks.forEach(link => window.open(link));
});

document.querySelector('#openLastGroupButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  lastGroupLinks.forEach(link => window.open(link));
});
```

Comment: Not necessarily what you want though - e.g. if there are 7 links, you'd get groups of length (3, 3, 1), whereas you might want more even distribution like (3, 2, 2). But OP didn't specify expected results so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yeah this one is for this specifc case.

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error. `Uncaught TypeError: links.slice is not a function`. What I just added to define the `links` constant is `const links = document.getElementsByClassName('tutslink');`

Comment: links must be array to use slice

Answer (score 1):

You can create chunck of links telling the size:

```
let links = [];//links array
let groupArr = [];
const groupSize = 3;
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i += groupSize) {
  const chunk = links.slice(i, i + groupSize);
  groupArr.push(chunk);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: links.slice is not a function`. Here is the code..

`let links = document.getElementsByClassName('tutslink'); //links array
let groupArr = [];
const groupSize = 3;
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i += groupSize) {
  const chunk = links.slice(i, i + groupSize);
  groupArr.push(chunk);
}
console.log(groupArr);`

Comment: @Abhik, try `let links = [...document.getElementsByClassName('tutslink')]`

Answer (score 1):

due to the number of links is whole number, why don't you round it up such as:

if you have 20 links, you divide your links into 7-7-6 ?

so you'll do:

```
  const list = [
   // whatever lists you have here
  ]; 
  const take = Math.ceil(list.length / 3);

  const firstList = links.slice(0,take);
  const secondList = links.slice(take, take*2);
  const thirdList = links.slice(take*2); // this will take until the end
```